# Switch on String before JDK 1.7

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I know there is a work around for this issue by applying `Enum`. But I find some limitations about it.

```
public void foo(String str) {
    Color color = Color.valueOf(str);
    switch (color) {
    case Green: /*do some stuff*/; break;
    case Red:   /*do some stuff*/; break;
    case Yellow:/*do some stuff*/; break;
    }
    //goes on
}
```

---

```
public enum Color{
    Green, Red, Yellow;
}
```

1. How can I somehow  make the `valueOf(str)` to ignore case?
2. How can I define the default behavior when the input `str` doesn't match any enum element? Apparently, adding a default clause in the switch statement is not the solution.
3. How can I accomplish all these in a clean way?

**EDIT:**
So the 1st question is solved according to RealSkeptic's helpful comment. I suppose now I can use `str.toUpperCase()`. How about the 2nd question?

**EDIT:**
So, according to aro_tech, for the 2nd question, I just need to add another enum element named `UNDEFINED`, then add the case clause for it.

```
public void foo(String str) {
    Color color = Color.fromString(str);
    switch (color) {
    case GREEN: /*do some stuff*/; break;
    case RED:   /*do some stuff*/; break;
    case YELLOW:/*do some stuff*/; break;
    case UNDEFINED:/*default behavior*/; break;
    }
    //goes on
}
```

---

```
   public enum Color{
        GREEN, RED, YELLOW, UNDEFINED;
        public static Color fromString(String stringName) {
            for(Color col : Color.values()) {
                if(col.name().equalsIgnoreCase(stringName)) {
                    return col;
                }
            }
            return UNDEFINED;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Java language conventions require that constant names be in ALL_CAPS. If you conform to these conventions, it's easy to convert any string to uppercase before applying `valueOf`.

Comment: Question 3 is very subjective, and probably depends on what "do some stuff" really means.  For complicated "stuff", switches are not very clean and should probably only be used in factory methods that choose the right object which will do the "stuff".  One slick trick that might work for you is to eliminate the switch altogether (keep the `fromString` method) and add "do some stuff" to a method of the enum itself. So you call something like `color.doSomeStuff(param1, param2);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your enum code and give it a static factory/lookup method:

```
public enum Color{
    Green, Red, Yellow;
    public static Color fromString(String stringName) {
        for(Color col : Color.values()) {
            if(col.name().equalsIgnoreCase(stringName)) {
                return col;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then change your main method's first line:

```
Color color = Color.fromString(str);
```

Of course, you may need to handle the special case of a null (a string that didn't match any enum entry).

Comment: For question 2, you could add `Undefined` to the enum and `fromString` could return `Undefined` instead of `null`.

Comment: If i were the user, I'd keep it as null and just add a 'default' case to the switch.

Comment: @aro_tech That's it! Thank you.